# How to set Volume for all activities in Android with a super class?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, audio, volume

I know how to set volume for one activity but I have multiple activity and I don't want to write the same code in all activity, so I tried to cut the snippet and made a super class which extends `AppCompatActivity` But I don't know how I can access this class for each activity.

So my VolumeController class looks like this:

```
public class VolumeController extends AppCompatActivity {

    AudioManager audioManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

        int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        SeekBar volumeControl = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        volumeControl.setMax(maxVolume);
        volumeControl.setProgress(currentVolume);

        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Log.i("Seekbar changed", Integer.toString(progress));

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Everything in the onCreate works fine if it's implemented in their own Activity onCreate method but it's not working if I created this VolumeController class...

My activity looks like this

```
public class GameActivity extends VolumeController {


    VolumeController volumeController = new VolumeController(); //Probably this is wrong?

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        //What to do here?

    }
```

I thought if I extend the VolumeController class it will inherit all methods and attributes from the super class?

Comment: You're doing it right except for the line "VolumeController volumeController = new VolumeController();"

Comment: I delete that like it still does not work.. I don't understand why this code works if it's in their activity but not work if I moved that code to a super class

Comment: I tried to put a Log in the onCreate method in the super class and it also doesn't not run the Log.. so I guess the onCreate method in the super class does not really work?

Comment: You have to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)` in your superclass, but you will have to pass the layout id to the superclass so that you can use this from multiple subclasses.

Comment: How do I pass the id? I have set an id to my activity_game now